# html sidebar pops to the left after loading

Tags: html, css, position, sidebar

i'm pretty much a noob, but i have a challenge: i am building a site with a sidebar for small screens, using a css template. In the demo, the nav bar is located on the right, however in my case it pops to the left after a js animation. Any ideas why and how to solve it?

It uses the following code:

```
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-right w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16">Close ×</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#team" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">TEAM</a>
    <a href="#work" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">WORK</a>
    <a href="#pricing" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">PRICING</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACT</a>
  </nav> -->
```

And the following css blocks

```
.w3-sidebar{height:100%;margin-right:0%;width:200px;background-color:#fff;position:fixed!important;z-index:1;overflow:auto}

.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:block!important}}

.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:none}

.w3-bar-block {width:100%}

.w3-bar-block {min-width:100%}

.w3-bar-block{width:100%;text-align:left;padding:8px 16px}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: can you share a sandbox for this?

Comment: Hi, i created a codepen environment:
https://codepen.io/gwert

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind for me is changing the "block" to "inline" at:

```
.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:block!important}}
```

to..

```
.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse{display:inline!important}}
```

You can maybe try that, but I'm not sure will it work... Hope it helped..

Comment: unfortunately no :( any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you maybe check if you've accidentally left a stylesheet (CSS) object property opened (without the second curly bracket at the end / bottom line).. Check that for all stylesheet (CSS) lines / properties

Comment: unfortunately no , checked everything :(

Comment: When I check the "inspect" page of your CodePen example, I find that there is this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I am not sure if this is an error connected to your project or to CodePen's website, but you might wanna look into that a bit..

Comment: You can also try opening the code in Visual Studio Code or some other code editor, and see if it will display any errors (if there is an error, it will display an error in the bar on the right [where all the code is all zoomed out] you will see red lines indicating an error, so find that section and see, do that for all files which are in any way connected to the project (which contain some code in them). If that doesn't work, then it also might be something related to the browser support, some browsers don't support some HTML tags, so that also might cause the issue you are having..

Comment: unfortunately it did not work :( no errors